# Using an explicity Column with a cell value from another sheet for Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

Using:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(F8),CONCATENATE(INDIRECT("'"&A8&"'!"C"&$K$26")," ",INDIRECT("'"&A8&"'!"D"&$K$26")),"")
```

everything works, but the `"D"&$K$26"`.  The error is in "D".

Comment: Meant to say The error is in "D", but both get the  error.

Comment: Remove that double quote between the `!` and the `C`.. I'm not sure how that's working with the `D` one since it has the same double quote, but it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Just to clarify (&A2&) refers to a cell that contains the sheet name, C and D are the explicit Columns and &$K$26 is the cell that contains the row number.

Comment: After doing what JNevill, I only get a #REF! now. That's an improvement.

Comment: To answer pnuts, I have a summary sheet that lists software, the version, days before a license expires.  The other sheets are clients with all the information in them. I get the Software and version from the client sheet (001-NLC1).  I know which row I want to the software (C) and version (D), but I need to know an ever changing row. I got the ever change row in a set location (K26). Does that help?

Comment: I just looked at the error for the rep.  A ref to a cell has changed. I will need to check that out before I get any more help.

Comment: It seems to be referencing everything correctly, but the C and D on the client sheet.

Comment: When I'm having a problem with a formula that uses `INDIRECT()` I take the bits out of `INDIRECT()` and stick it in it's own cell to make sure that it's actually a cell location that is being built through the concatenation. In your case, stick `="'"&A8&"'!"C"&$K$26"` and `="'"&A8&"'!"D"&$K$26"` in a new cell and see what's coming out of that. If that works, then stick `=INDIRECT()` around those in their own cells and see if it's erroring. It's a quick way to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you  very much for your help.  I still got #REF!, but I decided instead to do the concatenating in the individual sheets so all I had to do was grab the cell in the client sheet and get the whole line I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct syntax, but whether suited to your requirement rather depends upon what that may be:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(F8),CONCATENATE(INDIRECT("'"&A8&"'!C"&K26)," ",INDIRECT("'"&A8&"'!D"&K26)),"")
```